# How to adjust the height of a div according to the content?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this and currently i'm doing a project and i'm stuck at this. I have 3 div's inside the main div. And i have to auto adjust the height of the div according to the content. Can any one suggest the solution for this. The code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

#rcorners2 {
position: absolute;
border-radius: 25px;
border: 2px solid #d3dce2;
padding: 20px;
width: 722px;
height:450px;
left: 151px;
top: 64px;
}
#img {
position: absolute;
width: 266px;
height: 260px;
left: 32px;
top: 42px;
}
#desc {
position: absolute;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
width: 373px;
left: 321px;
top: 42px;
height: 100%;
line-height:1.6;
}
.vr {
width: 2px;
background-color: #d3dce2;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 310px;
height: 317px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p>Rounded corners for an element with a border:</p>
<div id="rcorners2">
<div id="img">
<img src="SLT-A99V_wSAL2470Z_lg.jpg" height="260px" width="265">
</div>
<div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="desc">
Photography studio management software that helps grow your     business,   frees up your time, automatically keeps in touch with your clients and makes sure all your jobs stay on track! Studio Ninja reminds you when tasks are due and keeps all your jobs on track and consistent. Just set it up once and never forget a thing again. Check out which jobs are coming up from one convenient location or easily integrate it with Google Calendar or iCalendar. Photography studio management software that helps grow your business, frees up your time, automatically keeps in touch with your clients and makes sure all your jobs stay on track! Studio Ninja reminds you when tasks are due and keeps all your jobs on track and consistent. Just set it up once and never forget a thing again. Check out which jobs are coming up from one convenient location or easily integrate it with Google Calendar or iCalendar.
 </div>
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: autoadjust `height` of which `div`?

Comment: I want to adjust the height of main div rcorners2.

Comment: Adjust it to which `height`? See here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6s2g0h2m/)** I've created using your code.. Can you just tel me what should be `height` of main `div`?

Comment: in your code i would like to auto adjust the height of the div according to the content. some times the desc div content will be more and some times less. So i want to adjust the height of desc div. And also change the height of main div rcorners2 and the vertical line div vr tag also. Thanks for your support.

Comment: what if the text contents from `desc` div exceeds.. you need `scroll` on that?

Comment: I dont want any scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The div that you want to adjust according to the content, for that div use a CSS of `min-height`.

**Example:**

```
.contentDiv{
  min-height:400px;
}
```

In **your case** it will be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

#rcorners2 {
position: absolute;
border-radius: 25px;
border: 2px solid #d3dce2;
padding: 20px;
width: 722px;
min-height:450px;
left: 151px;
top: 64px;
}
#img {
position: absolute;
width: 266px;
height: 260px;
left: 32px;
top: 42px;
}
#desc {
font-size: 16px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
width: 373px;
height: 100%;
line-height: 1.6;
margin-left: 321px;
}
.vr {
width: 2px;
background-color: #d3dce2;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 310px;
height: 317px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p>Rounded corners for an element with a border:</p>
<div id="rcorners2">
<div id="img">
<img src="SLT-A99V_wSAL2470Z_lg.jpg" height="260px" width="265">
</div>
<div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="desc">
Photography studio management software that helps grow your     business,   frees up your time, automatically keeps in touch with your clients and makes sure all your jobs stay on track! Studio Ninja reminds you when tasks are due and keeps all your jobs on track and consistent. Just set it up once and never forget a thing again. Check out which jobs are coming up from one convenient location or easily integrate it with Google Calendar or iCalendar. Photography studio management software that helps grow your business, frees up your time, automatically keeps in touch with your clients and makes sure all your jobs stay on track! Studio Ninja reminds you when tasks are due and keeps all your jobs on track and consistent. Just set it up once and never forget a thing again. Check out which jobs are coming up from one convenient location or easily integrate it with Google Calendar or iCalendar.
 business, frees up your time, automatically keeps in touch with your clients and makes sure all your jobs stay on track! Studio Ninja reminds you when tasks are due and keeps all your jobs on track and consistent. Just set it up once and never forget a thing again. Check out which jobs are coming up from one convenient location or easily integrate it with Google Calendar or iCalendar. Photography studio management software that helps grow your business, frees up your time, automatically keeps in touch with your clients and makes sure all your jobs stay on track! Studio Ninja reminds you when tasks are due and keeps all your jobs on track and consistent. Just set it up once and never forget a thing again. Check out which jobs are coming up from one convenient location or easily integrate it with Google Calendar or iCalendar.
 </div>
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Replace height to min-height as by using height property you are telling browser to restrict the div to that particular height and not extend beyond it. So replacing it with a minimum height property will make your div flexible to set according to it's contents.

With this your div will always have a **minimum height** of 450px and will extend it's height depending on the content that you put inside it.

I hope it will do the job for you. If not please comment.

Comment: Thnks for your answer. I it didn't work for me. I add extra content to the desc div the content overflowing.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But the same result is showing. It did'nt work for me. I changed it into min-height and I add extra content to it. and the content overflowing.

Comment: It was the position absolute which was not allowing it to work.

Comment: Be careful while using position absolute. In your example here you have used it three times but I think all this can be achieved easily without using position absolute. I could not spend the time to modify it entirely, but I did modify a bit just to show you where you were having the issue